# Двоеточие или запятая? (1)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

**Соберу их они ещё пригодятся.**

Какой поставить знак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Соберу их: они ещё пригодятся.***

Второе предложение указывает на причину того, о чём говорится в первом; в БСП с такими отношениями ставится двоеточие.

Comment: Всегда ставится двоеточие? А если поставить тире или запятую, то это будет ошибкой?

Comment: А вот правило такое есть, значит надо двоеточие ставить? Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно или несколько предложений, не соединенных с первым посредством cоюзов и заключающих в себе: а) разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чем говорится в первом предложении, б) основание, причина того, о чем говорится в первом предложении

Comment: Двоеточие - классическое решение задачи. Автор текста может ДОПУСТИТЬ и тире, и запятую. Но лучше пользоваться основным правилом.

Answer (score 3):

**Соберу их, они ещё пригодятся.**

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП), вторая часть имеет значение **причины,** поэтому **по общим правилам** здесь можно поставить любой знак: классическое двоеточие, тире, заменяющее двоеточие, но можно поставить и запятую.

Запятая ставится в БСП с **неоднородными** отношениями между простыми предложениями, когда второе предложение **распространяет** первое. Запятая характерна **для разговорного стиля, для нераспространенных предложений**, когда не имеет смысла использовать такие "сильные" знаки, как тире и двоеточие.

Разные знаки соответствуют разной **интонации**: при постановке двоеточия или тире между предложениями делается **увеличенная пауза**.

Comment: Смысл слов "второе предложение распространяет первое" не совсем понятен. Можно сказать простыми словами, что запятая делает акцент на последовательности событий, в отличие от двоеточия и тире, указывающих на причинно-следственную связь?

Comment: Последовательность  (или одновременность) событий выражают БСП с  однородными отношениями (открытая структура, любое количество предложений), а здесь неоднородные отношения (причинно-следственные, закрытая структура, только два предложения). Пример   предложения с последовательными событиями:  "Из коридора выехала на резиновых колесиках кушетка, на нее переложили затихшего Ивана..." Мы просто не обозначаем  причинно-следственные отношения, но  они подразумеваются по смыслу.

Comment: А вот правило такое есть, значит надо двоеточие ставить? Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно или несколько предложений, не соединенных с первым посредством cоюзов и заключающих в себе:

а) разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чем говорится в первом предложении, б) основание, причина того, о чем говорится в первом предложении

Comment: А еще такое правило есть: Примечание 2. В бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении пояснения, ПРИЧИНЫ, обоснования, изъяснения допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике). http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

Comment: И как быть в данном случае?)))

Comment: Если это учебный текст, то ставьте двоеточие.  В художественных  и газетных текстах  автор может выбрать знак  (по интонации, по смыслу, по структуре предложения). Вот пример с запятой у  Лопатина:  При отсутствии предупредительной интонации двоеточие "в этих случаях не ставится: Сейчас не поедешь, жарко (Ч.). Вот что рекомендует Розенталь: "Двоеточие употребляется в тех синтаксических условиях, где может наиболее проявиться его разъяснительно-пояснительная функция".